# Error in data.frame with rm.outlier function

Tags: r, runtime-error, outliers

I have a data frame 1488 obs. and 400 var. I am trying to log all the values in the table and then using the package outliers with the command rm.outlier, I am tyring to remove the outliers. The only problem is that I get this error:

```
Error in data.frame(V1 = c(-0.886056647693163, -0.677780705266081, -1.15490195998574,  : arguments imply differing number of rows: 1487, 1480, 1481, 1475, 1479, 1478, 1483, 1485, 1484, 1477, 1482, 1469
```

This is my code:

```
datalog <- matrix(0,nrow(data),ncol(data))
datalog[,] <- apply(data,2,log10)
datalog[datalog==-Inf] <- 0
datalog <- as.data.frame(datalog, stringsAsFactors=F)

testNoOutliers <- rm.outlier(datalog, fill = FALSE, 
                         median = FALSE, opposite = FALSE)
```

My data:
https://skydrive.live.com/redir?resid=CEC7696F3B5BFBC6!341&authkey=!APiwy6qasD3-yGo

Thanks for any help

Comment: Welcom to SO! what is your testlog function?

Comment: oh right sorry I have different names in my thing. Just rename testlog to datalog.

Comment: When I load your file I have more than 1488 obs , I have 7968 obs (number lines)!Is it the right data file?

Comment: It wasn't the right file sorry. I changed the link, should be fine now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You got this error because different number of outliers are removed from each column and so columns can not be put together in one data frame.

If you want to replace outliers with NA, one solution would be

```
out.rem<-function(x) {
  x[which(x==outlier(x))]=NA
  x
}

apply(datalog,2,out.rem)
```

To remove entire rows containing outlier values, you could add additional line to @agstudy solution

```
ll <- apply(datalog,2,function(x) which(x == outlier(x)))
new.datalog <- datalog[-unique(unlist(ll)),]
```

Comment: The rm.outliers removes only 1 outlier from each column so it should still be fine. In the end 400 values should be removed.

Comment: If you read error message that says "arguments imply differing number of rows: 1487, 1480, 1481,..." you can see that number of rows in each column is different. You could try it by using function on some columns separetaly.

Comment: But it only implies that. Sorry I'm new to R. I did the describe() function from the Hmisc package and each column still had 1488 rows. Any suggestions on how to amend this error?

Comment: Number of rows is different after outlier removal, not in datalog. Solution depends on decision what to do to values in other columns in the same row - remove whole row of 400 variables if one variable have outlier?

Comment: I would prefer to replace the value with NA if possible. But if you don't mind could you also show me how to remove the entire row? Thank you for you help

Answer (score 1):

You got the error because you don't have the same number of outlier bar variable.

To correct it you have 2 options :

1. put the option **fill = TRUE** :the mean is placed instead of outlier and not removed
2. Remove the oulier by yourself:

   ```
     # get a list of outlier index for each variable
     ll <- apply(datalog,2,function(x) which(x == outlier(x)))
   ```